# Postgresql - update a huge table in chuncks

Tags: postgresql, plsql

I have a table with 8million rows. I want to update this table by batches.

The flow looks like this,(update 1000 rows first and commit then start u[pdate from 2000(1000+1000).

```
    DO$$
    DECLARE i integer;
    DECLARE c integer;


    C := 1000;
    D := c+100;
    i := (SELECT max(id) from test); 


    So the update query will look like,


    begin
    if c <=i
    then

    update table test set id=id+1 where id>=C and id <=i
    C=D;

    Else
    end$$

    Loop2
    Loop3

    End$$
```

Can anyone help me to build this query?

Comment: A warning: if you’re updating id to go one higher and looping upwards you may get collisions if you have unique indexes or duplicate values if you don’t. Looping should go the other way from the increment/decrement.

Comment: Its not unique, and its an example query. Actually Im going to update another column like col=col+id

Comment: if you want commit - you need scripting outide of PlPgSql (unless you use dblink or some other hack of course)

Comment: Modified, so my intention is just update this table via batches. So commit is not mandatory.

Comment: How do you know if you succeeded in updating them all successfully? If you have rights, I would add a column to the table that you can set to know you've updated the row (with the old id or a date), then you can just update that table in chunks of n (your chunk size) where the updated column is null. Or create a temp table with the ctid of the row IDs you have updated and only update rows in your table with row IDs not in that temp table. Then delete the temp table or temp column.